# What is the chance of 3 particular numbers, occurring in 6 randomly generated numbers?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say I generate $6$ numbers: $X_1, \ldots, X_6$

where $X_i$ can be any integer between $1$ and $59$ with equal probability (inclusive).

For example, the following could have been randomly generated:

$$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 59$$

$$1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 59$$

$$\text{etc}\ldots$$

What is the chance that $1,2,3$ is a  subset of the $6$ numbers generated?

What is the chance that $1,1,3$ is a  subset of the $6$ numbers generated?

And in general,

What is the chance that $x,y,z$ is a  subset of the $6$ numbers generated?

**Edit:** As per the definition of "subset", order does not matter. So $1,2,3$ is a subset of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ as well as $1,6,3,5,2,4$

Comment: If one speaks of a "subset", one would normally write $\{1,2,3,\}$ rather than $1,2,3$, and if the sequence is $30,3,15,1,37,29,2,14,\ldots$, then $\{1,2,3\}$ is a subset.  But if one were to write $\{1,1,3\}$ that would be the same as the set $\{1,3\}$, so I wonder if you meant that the _sequence_ $1,1,3$ occurs.  Your later edit says order does not matter.  Did you intend that if $3,2,1$ occur in that order, then $1,2,3$ is what you call a "subset"?  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I guess he really means a multiset?

Comment: When you write $1,1,3,$ do you mean that $1$ occurs exactly twice, and $3$ occurs exactly once in the six numbers generated ?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, derpy is correct, the correct terminology would be multiset, so the multiset needs to be contained within the 6 generated numbers (it doesn't matter what the positions are), so $1,1,2$ is contained in $1,1,2,3,4,5$ and $2,1,3,4,5,1$ but not in $1,2,3,4,5,6$, are curly braces valid for multisets?

Comment: @trueblueanil it doesn't need to be exactly once, it just needs to be contained within the 6 numbers, e.g. $1,1,3$ is contained within $1,1,1,3,3,3$ but not $1,3,10,11,12,13$

Comment: @lottoguy : After the later edit that says order doesn't matter he gives an example of two sequences in which $1,2,3$ occurs in the _same_ order in both sequences.  So it remains unclear what was intended.

Comment: @MichaelHardy good catch, I shuffled it around it bit so it should be clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that ${a, a, b}$ is not the same as ${a, b},$ we can solve the problem using basic combinations.

In a set with six elements, $S = \{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{4}, a_{5}, a_{6}\},$ there are $\dbinom{6}{3} = 20$ "subsets" of $S$ with three elements in it. If there are $59$ numbers to choose from, we can construct a total of $59 + 2 \cdot \dbinom{59}{2} = 3481$ distinct sets of three numbers (that are not necessarily different).

The probability is simply $\boxed{\frac{20}{3481}},$ which is about $0.57\%.$

Answer (score 0):

$$Pr(1,2,3\text{ in set})=Pr(\text{three numbers in }\{1,2,3\})Pr(1,2,3 \text{ all included})\\
+Pr(\text{four numbers in }\{1,2,3\})Pr(1,2,3 \text{ all included})+...\\
={6\choose3}(\frac3{59})^3(\frac{56}{59})^3\frac6{27}+
{6\choose4}(\frac3{59})^4(\frac{56}{59})^2\frac{36}{81}+...$$
By Inclusion-Exclusion, Pr(1,2,3 all in five)=$(3^5-3.2^5+3.1^5)/3^5$, and
Pr(1,2,3 all in six)=$(3^6-3*2^6+3*1^6)/3^6$.  I get about 0.00054
The odds will be different for $1,1,2$.  3/59 becomes 2/59, and Pr(1,1,2 all included) is different.  I get about 0.000275

Comment: This seems like it's right, let me think about it some more